# How to convert python dataframe to JSON

Tags: python, json, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am utilizing pyspark in a databricks environment and I have a dataframe as below:

```
display(TestDF)

Count          Value
10             Blue
5              Green
21             Red
```

How can I convert the DF into a JSON format as below:

```
{"Blue":10,"Green":5,"Red":21}
```

I have tried below, however, the JSON is not quite in the right format as above

```
TestDF = TestDF.tojson()

{"count":10,"value":"Blue"}
{"count":5,"value":"Green"}
{"count":21,"value":"Red"}
```

Thanks.

Comment: As above via {"Blue" :10,......}

Comment: Does `tojson` have any control parameters?  You may have to transform the dataframe in some way.  It looks like `tojson` creates a dictionary for each `row`, and a key for each column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use **`map_from_arrays`** from **`Spark-2.4+`** and **`collect_list`** on **`count,value`** columns.

```
#if count type is not int then cast to array<int>
df.agg(to_json(map_from_arrays(collect_list(col("Value")),collect_list(col("Count")).cast("array<int>"))).alias("json")).\
show(10,False)

#if count type int then no need to casting
df.agg(to_json(map_from_arrays(collect_list(col("Value")),collect_list(col("Count")).cast("array<int>"))).alias("json")).\
show(10,False)
#+------------------------------+
#|json                          |
#+------------------------------+
#|{"Blue":10,"Green":5,"Red":21}|
#+------------------------------+

#get as string
df.agg(to_json(map_from_arrays(collect_list(col("Value")),collect_list(col("Count")).cast("array<int>"))).alias("json")).collect()[0][0]
#or
df.agg(to_json(map_from_arrays(collect_list(col("Value")),collect_list(col("Count")).cast("array<int>"))).alias("json")).collect()[0]['json']
#{"Blue":10,"Green":5,"Red":21}
```

Comment: when I use this method and print I get as below: ` +---------+
|json                                                                                                                                                                                    |
+-------------+ |{"Blue":10,"Green":5,"Red":21} | +-------------+  `    how do I just get the string: {"Blue":10,"Green":5,"Red":21}     any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: @Techno04335, Try with `df.agg(to_json(map_from_arrays(collect_list(col("Value")),collect_list(col("Count")).cast("array<int>"))).alias("json")).collect()[0][0]`

Comment: Thanks for your help!